# Parsing XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am calling a third-party web service. This service returns responses in plain old xml. A sample response looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.somedomain.com/Response.xsd">
  <Results>
    <Result>
      <ID>1</PointID>
      <Name>Testing</Name>
    </Result>
  </Results>
</Response>
```

I am trying to load this XML into CLR objects via LINQ. My CLR object declaration looks like the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
  private int id = 0;

  private string name = string.Empty;

  [DataMember]
  public int ID
  {
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
  }

  public Result()
  {

  }
}
```

In an attempt to load this XML into the CLR objects, I'm going with the following approach:

```
string response = UseWebService();
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(response);

var results = from result in xml.Descendants().Descendants()
              select new Result
              {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(result.Descendants("ID")),
                Name = result.Descendants("Name").ToString()
              };

List<Result> resultList = results.ToList();
return resultList;
```

When I use this code, I receive an Exception that says

```
Unable to cast object of type '<GetDescendants>d__a' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

If I comment out the line that say "ID = Convert.ToInt32..." it works. But, the Name gets set to "System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+d__a". What am I doing wrong? I just want to load the XML into some POCOs.

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

`Descendants` is a collection of Objects so you need to get a single instance of it.

So do something like this

`Name = result.Element("Name").Value.ToString`

Comment: Why do I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error with this approach? This is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned descendants is a list of objects so you need to get its value, the default ToString() will be the name of the object.

```
var results = from result in xml.Descendants().Descendants()
                  select new Result
                  {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(result.Descendants("ID").Value),
                    Name = result.Descendants("Name").Value
                  };
```